# AngularJS: Validators in Controller no binding with HTML side

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

All in-line validations in HTML side are working OK, but when I use functions in my Controller (functions ingresarNuevoEmpleador and limpiarNuevoEmpleador), always get $invalid=true. $setPristine neither works.
Apparently both sides are referencing different objects because controller functions 
do not modify the state of the html side validators.

```
<form name="frmEmpleadorDirecto" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8">
       <div class="form-group has-feedback" 
        ng-class="{'has-error': frmEmpleadorDirecto.nempleador.$invalid && (frmEmpleadorDirecto.nempleador.$touched || frmEmpleadorDirecto.$submitted)}">
          <label for="input501">Empleador Directo</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" name="nempleador" placeholder="Nombre Empleador" ng-model="objEmpleador_.nombreEmpleador_" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="30" ng-required="true">
          <span class="help-block" ng-if="frmEmpleadorDirecto.nempleador.$error.minlength && frmEmpleadorDirecto.nempleador.$touched">too short</span>
          <span class="help-block" ng-if="frmEmpleadorDirecto.nempleador.$error.maxlength && frmEmpleadorDirecto.nempleador.$touched">too long</span>
          <span class="help-block" ng-if="frmEmpleadorDirecto.nempleador.$error.required && frmEmpleadorDirecto.nempleador.$touched">required</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-mm" ng-disabled="frmEmpleadorDirecto.$pristine || frmEmpleadorDirecto.$invalid" ng-click="ingresarNuevoEmpleador()">Aceptar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-mm" ng-click="limpiarNuevoEmpleador()">Limpiar</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.empleador_')
      .controller('CtrlEmpleadorNuevo',CtrlEmpleadorNuevo);

 function CtrlEmpleadorNuevo($scope,$http,$rootScope) {

  $scope.objEmpleador_ = new eva.Empleador_();


  $scope.ingresarNuevoEmpleador = function()
     {
    console.log("Nombre: " + $scope.objEmpleador_.nombreEmpleador_); //OK
        if($scope.objEmpleador_.$valid)  //always invalid
        {

        console.log('valid!');
        }else {
          console.log('invalid!');        }

    }

    $scope.limpiarNuevoEmpleador = function () 
    {

        $scope.objEmpleador_.$setPristine; //no changes
       $scope.objEmpleador_.nombreEmpleador_ = ''; //Works: reset html field

    }
}
```

Objects:

```
eva.Empleador_ = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.nombreEmpleador_ = '';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is bound on your $scope and inputs and their validity can be reached following the name attribute.

```
  $scope.ingresarNuevoEmpleador = function(){
    console.log("Nombre: " + $scope.objEmpleador_.nombreEmpleador_); //OK
        if($scope.frmEmpleadorDirecto.nempleador.$valid) {
        console.log('valid!');
        }else {
          console.log('invalid!');        
        }

    };
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DtxkXmtTodIn88XC078M?p=preview)

Comment: angular.js:12798 TypeError: Cannot read property 'nempleador' of undefined
    at ChildScope.CtrlEmpleadorNuevo.$scope.ingresarNuevoEmpleador(CtrlEmpleadorNuevo.js:17)

Comment: Can you please check the plunker. I get no errors and the console displays when the button is pressed.